# search and scrolling in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i want to search in text and scrolling on find line. i can not develop this code for scrolling to found `<h3>` tag line.

jQuery:

```
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
         var page = $('#all_text');
         var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
         var searchedText = $.trim($('#searchfor').val());
         var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
         var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
         page.html(newHtml);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchfor"/>
<p id="all_text">
<h3>LINE 1</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinci futurum.<b>EX1</b><br/>
<h3>LINE 2</h3>        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinci futurum.<b>EX2</b><br/>
.
.
.
<h3>LINE 100</h3>        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinci futurum.<b>EX100</b><br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net What is working so far?

Comment: What exactly do you intend this to do?  It looks like what it's trying to do is nuke all of the vanilla span tags off the page, then wrap a vanilla span tag around all examples of the given string.  I can't tell you whether or not you have your syntax right, but as shown, it will have troubles with ugly overlapping tag issues as soon as you start writing in tags.  Both `<span><h</span>3>LINE 1</h3>` and `<span><h3></span>LINE 1</h3>` are problematic in their own ways

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to scroll to the span that you just added `<span>$1</span>`

```
 $("span").scrollintoview();
```

Note that it will not scroll if the span is already in the visible area.

**Upadate**
Missed to mention the plugin before.
This is the link to the [Plugin Page](http://erraticdev.blogspot.in/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html)

Comment: this reqiures a plugin that you didn't mention , and that the question didn't mention either

Comment: Sorry.. I missed to give the link. Added the link now